# Calculating the average degree/valency of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees

If I were to let *T* be a tree with *n* vertices, what would be the average degree/valency of the vertices in *T*? How would I go about calculating this?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

(i) How many edges does a tree on $n$ vertices have?

(ii) Each edge of a graph contributes $2$ to the total degree sum of the graph.

This allows you to calculate the total degree sum for a tree on $n$ vertices, and from this you can find the average degree.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the definition of degree of a vertex in a graph, then you can easily calculate the average valency of a tree.

If $K$ is the average valency, then we have 
$$K=\frac{1}{n}(\deg(v_1)+\deg(v_2)+\ldots+\deg(v_n)),$$ where $n$ is the total number of vertices in a tree, $\deg(v_1)$ is the degree(valency) of $v_1$ (first vertex) and so on.